# Incremental search for chat user or room doesn't work

Tags: bug, chat, search

Incremental [search for chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search) user or room doesn't work as expected:

> [image: no search]

I.e. typing new letters doesn't refresh drop-down list content.

If I do typing very quick it works some times:

> [image: quick search]

Comment: Do you often search for your own name on the Internet?

Comment: @rene only in cases of self-advertisment :)